# Android - OpenCV Template Matching with threshold

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv

I am new to OpenCV and I have been looking at tutorials plus the questions around here but I have not been able to understand and set a threshold to the template matching.

This is the code I am currently using.
Function that will be **triggered when picture selected**

```
BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgView.getDrawable();
Bitmap viewBitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
Bitmap bitmapMatch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.template_1);

run(viewBitmap, bitmapMatch, "result.png", Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
```

**Run** function

```
public void run(Bitmap inFile, Bitmap templateFile, String outFile, int match_method) {
        System.out.println("\nRunning Template Matching");

        Mat img = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(inFile, img);
        Mat templ = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(templateFile, templ);

        // / Create the result matrix
        int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
        int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
        Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

        // / Do the Matching and Normalize
        Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
//        Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

        // / Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
        Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

        Point matchLoc;
        if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
            matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
        } else {
            matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "point: " + mmr.maxVal);

        // / Show me what you got
//        Core.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
//                matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(255, 255, 255));

        // Save the visualized detection.
        System.out.println("Writing "+ outFile);

        if (match >= 0.8)
            SaveImage(img,outFile);
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "No Match Found");
    }
```

I would like to add a threshold at the if statement `if (match >= 0.8)` in order to save the image if the match is equal or over the threshold (0.8). If not, the image will not be saved.

Please help and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Core.MinMaxLocResult` contains `maxLoc`, `maxVal`, `minLoc`, and `minVal` values.  Just assign `match=mmr.maxVal` or `match=mmr.minVal` depending on context.

Alternatively, you could index in the `result` Mat to get your value and then test if it's over 0.8 as so:

```
double[] resultVal = result.get(matchLoc.y, matchLoc.x);
if (resultVal[0] >= 0.8) ...
```

Comment: I have used both minVal gives me lower than 0.0 and when i use maxVal i get no more than 0.075. I know the maxVal should be close to 1 because the template came from the image i am trying to match.

when i use maxLoc i get the following value `{273.0, 6.0}`. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: It depends on which method you are using. `TM_CCOEFF` and `TM_CCOEFF_NORMED` can be negative when there is negative correlation.  `TM_SQDIFF` and `TM_SQDIFF_NORM` should never be negative -- but with those two methods a perfect match is a 0, not a 1.

Comment: it wont work since `result.get(int,int)` expect int and matchLoc.y, matchLoc.x are doubles.